# Replace empty string with Non-Disclosed

Tags: java

I am a novice in Java so please pardon my inexperience. I have a column (source) like below which has empty strings and I am trying to replace it with Non-Disclosed.

```
Source

Website
Drive-by
Realtor
Social Media

Billboard

Word of Mouth

Visitor
```

I tried:

```
String replacedString = Source.replace("", "Non-Disclosed");
```

After running the above snippet, everything gets replaced by Non-Disclosed:

```
Non-Disclosed
Non-Disclosed
Non-Disclosed
............
```

How can I tackle this issue? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: By empty string do you mean empty line? Also will this line really be empty, what if it has some spaces/tabulators?

Comment: Yes, Empty Line....no data exists in those designated cells. And that is the reason I am trying to replace with `Non-Disclosed`.

Comment: What about `Source.trim().isEmpty() ? "Non-Disclosed" : Source;` ?

Comment: Do you have this column as one string, or will each line be represented as separate string?

Comment: This column is a string data type.

Comment: @AxelH The OP needs to process each line contained in the string, not the string as a whole.

Comment: But is it like `String[] rows = {"Source", "", "Website", ...}` or `String rows = "Source\n\nWebsite\n...";`?

Comment: @SantiBailors "_. I have a column (source) like below which has empty strings_" since String is plural, I see multiple instance.

Comment: `Source.trim().isEmpty() ? "Non-Disclosed" : Source;` This took care of it. Thanks @ AxelH.

Comment: @AxelH My understanding was that the OP had one string with line separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 String replacedString = Source.trim().isEmpty() ? "Non-Disclosed" : Source;
```

to replace only the "blank" String.

Answer (score 3):

I think you simply have to do : `Source.replace("\n\n", "\nNon-Disclosed\n")`

Comment: This will fail for text separated with `\r` or `\r\n`.

Comment: @Pshemo, yeah for sure.

Comment: And like I though, he read the source line per line, not in one String. (this was not clear)

Comment: hahaha i've seen, well we tried all to help. good job guys :)

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that your entire column is stored in one string.

In that case you can use `^$` regex to represent empty line (with MULTILINE flag `(?m)` which will allow `^` and `$` to represent start and end of lines).
This approach

- will work for many line separators `\r` `\n` `\r\n`
- will not consume those line separators so we don't need to add them back in replacement part.

To use regex while replacing we can use `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` method

DEMO:

```
String text = "Source\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "Website\r\n" + 
        "Drive-by\r\n" + 
        "Realtor\r\n" + 
        "Social Media\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "Billboard\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "Word of Mouth\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "Visitor";
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)^$", "Non-Disclosed");
System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
Source
Non-Disclosed
Non-Disclosed
Non-Disclosed
Website
Drive-by
Realtor
Social Media
Non-Disclosed
Billboard
Non-Disclosed
Word of Mouth
Non-Disclosed
Visitor
```